# Stopping FlexUnit test run, if a test fails?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, integration-testing, flexunit

I use FlexUnit 4.1 with Adobe's TestRunnerBase to run a suite of integration tests to verify the integrity of a 3-tier BlazeDS/Java EE/MySQL server.

To bypass the security checks enforced by Apache Shiro while running those tests, I have configured two separate test runs: One that logs in as root, one that performs the actual integration tests.

Because of the way that BlazeDS handles duplicate sessions (this is an issue for another question, or rather, it has been already), sometimes the login mechanism fails - in which case I would like the TestRunner to suspend all further activities.

I have looked all over for some way to configure FlexUnitCore to stop on a test failure, but to no avail.  Also, there seem to be events only for TEST_START and TEST_COMPLETE, but not for TEST_FAIL.

Is there some other way to find out if a test failed, to stop the runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time for me - I stumbled upon the solution to my problem while I was writing my question: There is an [IRunListener](http://docs.flexunit.org/asdocs/org/flexunit/runner/notification/IRunListener.html) interface that can be implemented to react to all sorts of information sent by the TestRunner. Then we simply use [FlexUnitCore#addListener()](http://docs.flexunit.org/asdocs/org/flexunit/runner/FlexUnitCore.html#addListener%28%29) to initialize it, the same way we do it with the UIListener, TraceListener, CIListener, etc. that Adobe provides.